# Running nix-shell on Mac M1

Tags: nix-shell, marlowe, marlowe-pioneer-program

I successfully installed NixOS on a Mac M1. However, running either `nix-shell` or `GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-shell` from within /marlowe-cardano (in the marlowe-pioneers branch) produces:

```
error: cannot bootstrap GHC on this platform ('aarch64-darwin' with libc 'defaultLibc')
```

Any ideas on how to get past this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you did a multi-user w/ daemon installation. I am aware that a functioning guide is [here](https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Environment/Build/Mac_M1/)

so get nix using the darwing unencrypted label

```
sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume
```

edit your `sudo nano /etc/nix/nix.conf`  file, by adding IOHK's binaries:

```
build-users-group = nixbld

substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=

system = x86_64-darwin
extra-platforms = x86_64-darwin aarch64-darwin

sandbox = false
extra-sandbox-paths = /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /usr/lib /private/tmp /private/var/tmp /usr/bin/env
experimental-features = nix-command
extra-experimental-features = flakes
```

reboot and you should be good to go.

**note** I am no Nix expert nut if the problem persists then you might need to completely uninstall Nix first, which is not so trivial.

Comment: This was spot on, thanks! 

I did have to [uninstall nix](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/installation/installing-binary.html#macos) first. Also needed to be in the /marlowe-cardano directory during installation in order to be able to run `nix-shell`.

Comment: Glad it worked! If you upvote and mark my answer as solved it will help other people find it ;)